# Get type of a struct fields within a `quote` macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have the following construct in a Derive procedural macro for generating a From implementation.

```
quote! {
  impl From<#other_struct_name> for #this_struct_name {
    fn from(other: #other_struct_name) -> Self {
      Self {
        #(#fields_from_other)*
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`other_struct_name` is an attribute defined by the user to indicate which struct to use to clone from. Within `fields_from_other` I have this

```
let fields_from_other = fields.iter().map(|f| {
    let ty = &f.ty;
    let name = &f.ident;
    quote! {
      #name: other.#name,
    }
});
```

`fields` are the fields of the struct I use the derive macro on so getting the type for those is not an issue. But how can I get the type of `other.#name` here? Eventually, I would like to check if it is an Option.

Comment: I'm not sure you can even get access to the other struct at all. Since macros run on the token stream they've been provided, you'd need to reach out and parse the source crate, in order to find the source type, in order to analyze it. Do procedural macros even get the amount of context which would allow for that?

Comment: I am very new to macros in general so I could not tell. Do you maybe have a hint on how to proceed if I would end up in a situation where parsing the source crate would be the only viable option?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get type information (which includes the fields belonging to a `struct`) at this point, because macro expansion happens on the AST, which is an untyped representation of the code. Consider also that if this were possible, what would happen if you applied your macro to two `struct`s which would reference each other?

Maybe you can achieve what you want without having type information? Since you mention "checking if a field is an `Option`", I'm guessing you want to apply different logic (like `unwrap_or_default()`) on `Option`-typed fields.

Some possible workarounds that come to mind:

- On the `struct` with the `derive` macro, you could annotate individual fields with a new attribute e.g. `#[unwrap]` or `#[unwrap_or(some_value)]`, then parse these attributes in the `derive` macro implementation.
- If the set of possible types in the fields is limited, you could create a `trait Copyable`, then implement `impl Copyable for i32 { ... }` as well as `impl Copyable for Option<i32> { ... }`. In the generated `From` implementation, you can then invoke these as e.g. `#field: Copyable::copy(&other.#field)`.

Comment: Thanks, now that I think more about the final result I want to achieve from this macro I would eventually also need to iterate over all fields of `other` as I need to know which fields are not represented in `this`. Unfortunately, I might not be able to do it with the proposed approaches.